# Custom file upload button with blueimp jquery file upload

Tags: jquery, file-upload, blueimp

I am struggeling with the jquery file upload plugin is uploading my file as soon as I choose the file in my input field.

I want to have a cusom submit button that upload the file..

How can I do this?

Markup:

```
<span>Add File</span>
<input id="fileupload" type="file" multiple="" data-url="upload.ashx" name="files[]" />

<label for="file_name">Name:</label>
<input type="text" name="file_name" id="file_name" />

<input type="button" id="uploadFileBtn" value="Upload" />
```

Javascript:

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload(
{
dataType: 'json',
done: function (e, data) {
    alert("success");                               
}
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**

The fileupload has an ADD event that triggers as soon as a file is selected. I wrote my click event inside the ADD event and thereby overriding default behaviour.

Tested and it works as expected.

**Solution 2 - Jquery Form Plugin**

After some researching I found a better way to deal with ajax fileupload. I am using the Jquery Form Plugin found at: http://www.malsup.com/jquery/form/

It works just like a regular form and can handle file inputs.

Comment: @martin-g look at this question how to do it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13304838/how-to-upload-a-file-only-once-with-jquery-file-upload-plugin

Comment: I have found another better way to deal with ajax fileuploading. I am using jquery form plugin. It works just like a regular form and can handle file inputs. http://www.malsup.com/jquery/form/

Answer (score 0):

Are your inputs inside the same form?

Changing you code:

```
<form id="fileupload" action="someAction" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <span>Add files</span>
    <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary start">
        <span>Start upload</span>
    </button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by hooking into the *add* event. There you prevent the uploader from doing its default behavior. The *jquery-file-upload*-docs explain that, but it's a bit hard to find.

The following is written in the [blueimp basic uploader tutorial](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Basic-plugin#how-to-start-uploads-with-a-button-click):

```
$(function () {
    $('#fileupload').fileupload({
        dataType: 'json',
        add: function (e, data) {
            data.context = $('<button/>').text('Upload')
                .appendTo(document.body)
                .click(function () {
                    data.context = $('<p/>').text('Uploading...').replaceAll($(this));
                    data.submit();
                });
        },
        done: function (e, data) {
            data.context.text('Upload finished.');
        }
    });
});
```

It actually is very important, that the submit button you're creating is not inside the form!